# Unique solutions to the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

Pierre-Gilles Lemarie-Rieusset, *The Navier-Stokes Problem in the 21st Century*  treats the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^3$ for time $t\geq 0$, and proves uniqueness of suitably smooth solutions by a kind of energy argument.  For a solution $u(t, x)$ with $u(0,x)=0$ he looks at the integral over all $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$
\begin{equation}\int |u(t,x)|^2 e^{-|x|}\,dx.\end{equation}
Using the equation $u_t=\Delta u$, calculations very like other energy proofs show
\begin{equation}
 \frac{d}{dt}\int |u(t,x)|^2 e^{-|x|}\,dx = -2\int |\vec{\nabla} u|^2 e^{-|x|}\,dx\ + 2\int u  e^{-|x|}  \sum_{j=1}^{3}\frac{x_j}{|x|}\partial_j u\,dx. 
\end{equation}
Those calculations begin with integration by parts and proceed by pretty straightforward calculus. Lemarie-Rieusset immediately concludes
\begin{equation}
  \frac{d}{dt}\int |u(t,x)|^2 e^{-|x|}\,dx \leq  \frac{1}{2}\int |u(t,x)|^2 e^{-|x|}\,dx.
\end{equation}
But I do not see how.

Comment: There must be some information missing. This can't be true in general simply because of the units: By rescaling $t$, one can always make it false.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt I believe the required information is just that $u$ solves the heat equation, which is in the question.  You cannot rescale $t$, preserving that equation, without rescaling $x$ also.

Comment: Ah yes, and it's that $e^{-|x|}$ factor that prevents one from simply undoing the $x$-scaling in the integral.

Comment: In the last integral where $u$ and $\nabla u$ appear, use Cauchy-Schwartz with respect to the weight $e^{-|x|}$ and $2ab \leq a^2/2+2b^2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, maybe my previous comment was not clear enough. You have $$\frac{d}{dt} \int |u|^2 e^{-|x|}\, dx=-2\int |\nabla u|^2 e^{-|x|}\, dx +2 \int u \nabla u \cdot \frac{x}{|x|}e^{-|x|}\, dx.$$
Now use $2|u \nabla u| \leq \frac 12 |u|^2+2|\nabla u|^2$
to estimate the last integral.

Comment: Now I see how to get it from $2|u \nabla u| \leq \frac 12 |u|^2+2|\nabla u|^2$ (using Cauchy-Schwarz as you said).  But how do you get that inequality?

Comment: It Is $2ab \leq a^2/2+2b^2$.

Comment: Oh yes, a routine quadratic inequality.

Comment: "routine quadratic inequality" A.K.A. $\varepsilon$-Cauchy-Schwarz: In analysis (of PDEs?) we use all the time that $|ab|\leq \varepsilon |a|^2+\frac{1}{\varepsilon}|b|^2$ for any $\varepsilon$ of one's liking or choosing. This is typically used to "reabsorb" the $|a|^2$ in the left-hand side of some inequality, just as in this thread.